# Trigonometric Anti-derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

What is $$\int \frac{\sin(x)^2}{\cos(x) + 1}dx\;?$$ I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't get it into a form that I can solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}(1-\cos x)$$ since $1-\cos^2x=\sin ^2x$ and $1-y^2=(1-y)(1+y)$

Comment: Why not: HINT: $\sin^2x=1-\cos^x=\ldots\;$? Oh, well. :-) (+1)

Comment: Argghhh. That should of course have been $1-\cos^2x$; the $2$ seems to have gone AWOL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That happened to kahen yesterday but with $\log^2x$. Curious.